# cross referencing other .ttl in Turtle RDF

Tags: file, reference, rdf, turtle-rdf

Is there a way for a .ttl file to contain references to other .ttl files? (to work as #include in C language)

Answer (score 5):

There's nothing at the level of Turtle itself, but you could use `owl:imports` for referencing other RDF files.

It's important to keep in mind though, that there is no obligation on the part of RDF-reading tools to actually process such an import-directive. Some tools will follow the link and read the referenced file, others will not.